# Topic "inventory.source.items.cleanup" is not configured

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade

[image]

I try to upgrade my magento 2 but i got this problem, how can i solve ? thanks

Comment: have you resolved this? i'm facing the same issue after installing a plugin

Comment: I don't know exactly, maybe I was solved 3 months ago but now I forget.

Comment: oh I found a way to resolve this and maybe this can help. I'm going to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

After a recent plugin installation, this occurred to me too. I got to resolve it by running `composer update`. If you are using an outdated version of Magento, you can download the archive from their website https://magento.com/tech-resources/download and replace the vendor folder and run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` again.